# Ajax in form submission with jquery and html

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a form submission page, call  a function  at the time of form submission.Include an ajax.Form submission occur or not according  to the condition in ajax.My code is given below.But it is not working.ANybody give any solution?

main page

```
    <form action="addCustomer_basic.php" method="post"
    name="adFrm"  onSubmit="return validate_form(this)" id="myform" >
    <tr class="oddRow">
     <td width="25%" align="right" valign="top" class="txt"><strong>Name
     : </strong></td>
       <td width="25%" align="left" valign="top">
     <input name="name" type="text"   
     class="txtfld" id="name"    
     value=">" style="width:250px;"/></td>
    <td width="25%" align="right" valign="top" class="txt">
    <strong>Reseller Name : </strong></td>
    <td width="25%" align="left"><input name="reseller_name" 
    id="reseller_name" ype="text" class="txtfld" 
    value="<?=$result_admin['phone_number'];?>"  style="width:250px;"/></td>

  </tr>
  <tr class="evenRow">
    <td align="right" valign="top" class="txt"><strong>Phone Number : </strong></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="phone_number"
    type="text" class="txtfld" id="phone_number" value=""  style="width:250px;"/></td>
    <td align="right" valign="top" class="txt"><strong>Email : </strong></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="email" type="text" 
    class="txtfld" id="email" value=""  style="width:250px;"/></td>
  </tr>
  </form>

 <script language="JavaScript">

 $(function() {

$("#myform").submit(function(e) {

    var $form = $(this);
    var cust_name = $form.find('[name="name"]').val();

    var email = $form.find('[name="email"]').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'ajx_customer_mailid.php',
      data:'cust_name='+cust_name + '&email=' + email,
      success: function(msg) 
      { 
      alert(msg);
         if(msg==1) 
         {
            alert("Email Id already excist");     
         }
         else 
         {
             $form.off('submit')
                  .submit();
         }
      }
   });

 return false;
```

});

});

```
 </script>
```

ajx_customer_mailid.php

```
 <?php
 require_once("codelibrary/inc/variables.php");
 require_once("codelibrary/inc/functions.php");
 $cust_id=$_POST['cust_name'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $se="select * from customer where name='$cust_id' and email='$email'";
 $se2=mysql_query($se);
 if($num>0)
 {
 echo $status=1;    
 }
else
{
   echo $status=0;  
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems. First, AJAX submissions are asynchronous unless you specify otherwise. That means that the function `validate_form` is returning, from the end of the function, before the AJAX call completes. Since it doesn't return false, the form POSTs normally.  Second, the `return` from inside your success handler returns from the handler itself - not the `validate_form` function.  To make this work, I would suggest that you always return false from `validate_form` and in your success handler, manually post the form (removing the submit handler first) when validation succeeds.

Note the code below attaches the handler via JavaScript and handles both validation and form submission on successful validation (`msg==1`)

```
$(function() {
    $('form[name="adFrm"]').on('submit', function(e) {
        var $form = $(this);
        var cust_name = $form.find('[name="name"]').val();
        var email = $form.find('[name="email"]').val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'ajx_customer_mailid.php',
          data:'cust_name='+cust_name + '&email=' + email,
          success: function(msg) { 
             if(msg==1) {
                alert(msg);     
             }
             else {
                 $form.off('submit')
                      .submit();
             }
          }
       });

       return false;   
     });
});
```

Comment: code's error is corrected,but dont get the value of email,alert is not working inside the submit code   $('form[name="adFrm"]').on('submit', function(e)
  {
  alert("email");

Comment: My requirement is msg==1 form not submit,but msg==0 or otherwise submit the form,but now form is not submitting in both case

Comment: Fixed the error - missing `);` There's a working fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/6o8xser9/

Comment: My code is edited,please look it,i got the msg value,msg have 2 values ,one value at a time.1 and 0.My requirement is msg=1 dont submit form,when msg=0 submit the form.But now dont submit form in both case.

Comment: Hi,can you give any solution for these issue plz

Comment: Change your PHP to return JSON and update the JS code accordingly. For example, `echo json_encode(('success' => 0));` then in your success handler `function (response) { if (response.success) {...}}`  If that doesn't work, then use the debugger to see what is actually being returned or if there are any errors making the request.